# Некорректная работа JUnit в Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, юнит-тесты, junit

Есть простейшее Spring Boot приложение:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Есть заготовка простейшего юнит-теста к нему:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws URISyntaxException {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:"+80;
        URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);
        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class);
        String s= result.getBody();     
    }
}
```

При запуске юнит-теста он пишет ошибку, что невозможно подключиться к серверу. Но, если запустить проект в "обычном" режиме, всё работает отлично и на экране браузера отображается "Hello World".

Использую Eclipse и JUnit 4.

Что я делаю не так?
Вывод в консоли ("обычный" режим):

```
2020-02-14 23:32:50.588  INFO 8220 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-UACCO14 with PID 8220 (D:\eclipse-W\demo\target\classes started by Егор in D:\eclipse-W\demo)
2020-02-14 23:32:50.598  INFO 8220 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-14 23:32:51.920  INFO 8220 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
2020-02-14 23:32:51.934  INFO 8220 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-02-14 23:32:51.934  INFO 8220 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2020-02-14 23:32:52.051  INFO 8220 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-02-14 23:32:52.052  INFO 8220 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1371 ms
2020-02-14 23:32:52.305  INFO 8220 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-02-14 23:32:52.564  INFO 8220 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 80 (http) with context path ''
2020-02-14 23:32:52.569  INFO 8220 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 2.499 seconds (JVM running for 3.513)
```

Вывод в консоли (запуск в режиме юнит-теста):

```
2020-02-14 23:21:32.571  INFO 7748 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests    : Starting DemoApplicationTests on DESKTOP-UACCO14 with PID 7748 (started by Егор in D:\eclipse-W\demo)
2020-02-14 23:21:32.574  INFO 7748 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-14 23:21:50.483  INFO 7748 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-02-14 23:21:51.376  INFO 7748 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests    : Started DemoApplicationTests in 19.882 seconds (JVM running for 23.085)
2020-02-14 23:22:37.781  INFO 7748 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Сообщение об ошибке в JUnit Runner:

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GET request for "http://localhost:80": Connection refused: connect;
>   nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect

Comment: Где в выводе написано, что невозможно подключиться к серверу?

Comment: @Bakhuss, добавил.

Comment: @VincentVega, порт можно настроить.

Answer (score 1):

В общем разобрался сам. В моём случае нужно вместо `@SpringBootTest` использовать аннотацию `@WebMvcTest` в сочетании с классом `MockMvc`.

Код рабочего юнит-теста:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(DemoApplication.class)
class DemoApplicationTests {

    private static final String ROOT_URL = "";
    private static final String HELLO_WORLD = "Hello World!";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(get(ROOT_URL)).andReturn();
        String s = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertTrue(s.equals(HELLO_WORLD));
    }
}
```

Источники, где я нашёл решение:

- [Unit Testing Rest Services with Spring Boot and JUnit (статья в блоге)](https://www.springboottutorial.com/unit-testing-for-spring-boot-rest-services);
- [Unit Testing Rest Services with Spring Boot and JUnit (вопрос на enSO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605095/unit-testing-rest-services-with-spring-boot-and-junit).