# Отключение интеграционных тестов при сборке Maven (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Есть проект на Spring Boot с интеграционными тестами наподобие тех, что в этом вопросе: [Некорректная работа JUnit в Spring Boot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1082785/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-junit-%D0%B2-spring-boot).

Проект собирается maven в облаке, где нет технической возможности ни поднять контекст приложения, ни тем более подключиться к БД или другим внешним ресурсам (из-за этого там проходят только обычные юнит-тесты). Получить такую возможность также нельзя по независящим от меня причинам.

В то же время проводить автоматические интеграционные тесты всё равно необходимо, т.к. проект развивается и затраты времени на ручное тестирование в обозримом будущем достигнут критических. Использовать везде Mockito то же не вариант, т.к. не всё можно заменить `Mock` объектами и не всегда такую замену сделать достаточно просто.

В поисках выхода из сложившейся ситуации, думаю каким-то образом отключить выполнение интеграционных автотестов для продакшена. Но, как это сделать? А, возможно данная проблема решается другим способом, но каким?

Comment: Как вариант сделать сборку базы через docker, и использовать этот образ в ci для интеграционных тестов

Comment: Отключить нужно не все тесты `mvn clean install -DskipTests`, а именно интеграционные?

Comment: Если вам нужно отключить тесты при сборке проекта, то просто добавьте напротив них анотацию `@Ignore` и они не будут собираться по умолчанию